# How to instal win32ole for ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, win32ole

Does anyone know the command to install win32ole for ruby. 
gem install win32ole does not work

I am trying to get require 'win32ole' to work

Comment: Depending on your installation of Ruby, it should be already included. `\Ruby192\lib\ruby\1.9.1`

Comment: I am using ruby 1.9.3 and when i add require 'win32ole' at the top of a script it just says cant find file

Comment: Excuse me for asking a stupid question but, are you using a Windows machine?

Comment: why the hate, i don't understand stackoverflow anymore

Comment: No hate from me. I'm sorry if it came across as such.

Answer (score 4):

`win32ole` is a gem for exposing the internal API for the Windows operating system. [Ruby on Windows](http://rubyonwindows.blogspot.com/) is a great blog that utilizes the gem to automate many Windows applications.

However, due to the fact that the gem relies heavily on exposing the Windows API (hence the name of the gem), the gem is not available on any other operating system but Windows.

Comment: Cheers. I am probably just better off using curb then